# Having issues writing my block, SYNTAX ERROR?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

if you need my to post other info i will!
but i believe this is just syntax?

not sure if it is wrong but i believe its written correctly.

```
SyntaxError: /Users/cod3/carbuilds/app/controllers/builds_controller.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected else else ^~~~ /Users/cod3/carbuilds/app/controllers/builds_controller.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected end end ^~~ /Users/cod3/carbuilds/app/controllers/builds_controller.rb:94: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end
```

this is my block code where its saying i am having the syntax error but i think its all right ,

correct me if i am wrong

```
class BuildsController < ApplicationController
    get '/builds' do
        if logged_in?
            @builds = Build.all 
            erb :'builds/index'
        else
            erb :'users/login' #locals: {message: "Unable to Continue please login"}
        end
    end

    get "/builds/new" do
        redirect_if_not_logged_in
        @build = Build.new
        erb :"/builds/new"
      end

    post '/builds' do
        redirect_if_not_logged_in
      if params.values.any? {|value| value == ""}
         erb :'builds/new', #locals: {message: "Unable to Continue!"}
      else
        user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        @build = Build.create(title: params[:title], budget: params[:budget], user_id: params[:user.id])
        redirect to "/builds/#{@build.id}"
      end
    end

    get 'builds/:id' do
        if logged_in?
            @build = Build.find(params[:id])
            erb :'builds/show'
        else
            erb :'users/login', #locals: {message: "Access Denied"}
        end
    end

    get 'builds/:id/edit' do
        if logged_in?
            @build = Build.find(params[:id])
            erb :'builds/edit'
        else
            erb :'users/login' #locals: {message: "Access Denied"}
        end
    end

    patch '/builds/:id' do 
        if params.values.any? {|value| value == ""}
           @build = Build.find(params[:id])
           erb :'builds/edit', locals: {message: "You're missing information"}
           redirect to "/builds/#{params[:id]}/edit"
        else
          @build = Build.find(params[:id])
          @build.title = params[:title]
          @build.budget = params[:budget]
          @build.save
          redirect to "/builds/#{@build.id}"
        end
    end

    delete '/builds/:id/delete' do 
         @build = build.find(params[:id])
        if session[:user_id]
            @build = Build.find(params[:id])
          if @build.user_id == session[:user_id]
             @build.delete
             redirect to '/builds'
          else
             redirect to '/builds'
          end
        else
            redirect to '/login'
        end
    end

    private

    def set_build 
        @build = build.find_by_id(params[:id])
        if @build.nil?
          flash[:error] = "Couldn't find a build with id: #{params[:id]}"
          redirect "/builds"
        end
      end
    
      def redirect_if_not_authorized
        redirect_if_not_logged_in
        if !authorize_build(@build)
          flash[:error] = "You don't have permission to do that action"
          redirect "/builds"
        end
      end
   end
end
```

this is my entire BuildsController file. Im creating a build a CAR BUILD app and it given me these syntax errors. If you have time i'd love to share it all with you so that you can see what i am doing. It is a big project but so far im down to just syntax so thats a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

1. There's an extra trailing comma in this line:

```rb
erb :'users/login', #locals: {message: "Access Denied"}
#                 ^ here
```

2. You probably have one too many closing `end`s at the end of the file.

You have incorrect block indentation in several places. Fix them, and it will be much easier to catch/avoid these issues altogether. A properly setup editor will even automate indentation formatting for you.

Sure, it is "just" syntax, but the syntax is important, as invalid syntax is unclear. The computer isn't going to *guess* what your intention was, so it means your code is effectively meaningless.

For example, a math syntax typo makes it impossible to definitively interpret:

```
(3 + 2 * 5
```

That expression could possibly mean any of:

- `(3) + 2 * 5` - possible missing `)` location
- `(3 + 2) * 5` - possible missing `)` location
- `(3 + 2 * 5)` - possible missing `)` location
- `3 + 2 * 5` - possible extra `(`

An example of unclear syntax in English that renders a sentence ambiguous (and thus factually meaningless): [image: Hitler, strippers, and oxford commas]

Comment: than you for answering and support! Love the picture reference!

Comment: Another example where the correct placement of commas is important: "Let's eat, grandpa!" vs. "Let's eat grandpa!"